# Como fazer um Spinner que só aceite números no PrimeFaces?

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando PrimeFaces para um projeto da faculdade. Como eu faço para que o "Spinner" não aceite "Caracteres" somente números?

```
Idade:
<p:spinner id="spinnerBasic"  max="120" value="#{spinnerController.number1}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, você pode resolver esse problema usando javascript conforme abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function onlyNumbers(data){
      data.value = data.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
   };
</script>
```

E no spinner use (*você pode alterar o momento da chamada caso queira, usando outro tipo de evento*):

```
<p:spinner id="spinnerBasic"  max="120" value="#{spinnerController.number1}" onkeyup="onlyNumbers(this)" />
```